# Finding the average of an array after dropping lowest value? (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a program that asks the user to input 5 numbers. The lowest of the 5 numbers will be dropped, and then the other 4 numbers are to be averaged.

I'm quite new to VB, but I believe I'm currently on the right path here...

I've sorted the array to help identify the lowest number, but I do not know how to exclude the lowest number and to then average the other remaining 4.

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim IntArr(4) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 5
            IntArr(4) = InputBox("Enter Number" & i)
        Next
        Array.Sort(IntArr)
        'textbox1.text = ???
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone please assist or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Best example of sorting arrays I know of, http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx but you might also want to search for "VBA EXCEL SIMPLE BUBBLE SORT"

Comment: Edited the tags.

Comment: Your code only populates `IntArr(4)`

Comment: Sorry, thought this was VBA, which doesn't have a .sort method for arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In keeping with the spirit of your code, something like the following would work.

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim IntArr(4) As Integer
      Dim OutArr(3) As Integer

      For i = 0 To 4
         IntArr(i) = InputBox("Enter Number " & i)
      Next

      Array.Sort(IntArr)
      Array.Copy(IntArr, 1, OutArr, 0, 4)  'exclude the lowest number
      TextBox1.Text = OutArr.Average()
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the help. It doesn't seem to be giving me the desired output though. If I enter in the numbers  5, 6, 7, 8,  and 1, once I remove the 1 (the lowest value) the average is 6.5. However, the output shows 0.25. Any idea why?

Comment: I would guess you need to change IntArr(4) to IntArr(i).  My code sample does produce an output of 6.5 and that is one difference between our code.

Comment: You're correct! Sorry I must have missed that portion. Thanks so much for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using built in LINQ functions

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numberOfItems = 5
    Dim numberOfItemsToRemove = 1
    Dim inArray(numberOfItems - 1) As Integer
    Dim outArray(numberOfItems - 1 - numberOfItemsToRemove) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To numberOfItems - 1
        While Not Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter Number " & i + 1), inArray(i))
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!")
        End While
    Next
    outArray = inArray.OrderBy(Function(j) j).Skip(numberOfItemsToRemove).ToArray()
    MessageBox.Show(
        String.Format(
            "Input: [{0}], Output: [{1}], average: {2:0.0}",
            String.Join(", ", inArray),
            String.Join(", ", outArray),
            outArray.Average))
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is above will continue to simply change the value of index 4 with each box if I'm not mistaken. I would do something like this (I will use your variable names for your convenience).

```
Button1_Click(procedure junk that is auto-inserted)

Dim intArr(4) As Integer
Dim OutArr(3) As Integer
Dim intCounter, intAverage, intLowest, intLowIndex As Integer

'populate all indexes of intArr()
For intCounter = 0 to 4
    intArr(intCounter) = InputBox("Please enter a number.")
Next intCounter

intCounter = 1                  'reset counter for check
intLowest = intArr(intLowIndex) 'start with index 0

'find lowest number and its index
For intCounter = 1 to 4
   If intLowest > intArr(intCounter) Then     'defaults to previous
       intLowest = intArr(intCounter)
       intLowIndex = intCounter
   End If
Next intCounter

intCounter = 0   'reset counter again for possible For...Next loops

Select Case intLowIndex
Case = 0
   For intCounter = 0 to 3
      OutArr(intCounter) = intArr(intCounter + 1)
   Next intCounter
Case = 1
  OutArr(0) = intArr(0)
  OutArr(1) = intArr(2)
  OutArr(2) = intArr(3)
  OutArr(3) = intArr(4)
Case = 2
  OutArr(0) = intArr(0)
  OutArr(1) = intArr(1)
  OutArr(2) = intArr(3)
  OutArr(3) = intArr(4)
Case = 3
  OutArr(0) = intArr(0)
  OutArr(1) = intArr(1)
  OutArr(2) = intArr(2)
  OutArr(3) = intArr(4)
Case = 4
  For intCounter = 0 to 3
    OutArr(intCounter) = intArr(intCounter)
  Next intCounter
End Select

intAverage = (OutArr(0) + OutArr(1) + OutArr(2) + OutArr(3)) / 4

'insert your preferred method to display OutArr() and intAverage
```